# iOS Facebook SDK Linking with Unity on Simulator Issue

Tags: ios, facebook, linker, simulator

Currently getting the following when trying to link for the simulator, works fine on hardware.  Using the latest Facebook SDK.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
 "_UnityGetGLViewController", referenced from:
  _FBNativeAdClick in FBAudienceNetwork(FBNativeAdCBridge.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Anyone else have seen this?

FB_AD_SDK_VERSION @"3.21.1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application using -all_load flag this happened.

You can use -force_load instead.

Comment: Going to accept this answer, after updating Facebook SDKs problem went away and was unable to test this answer.